Cloudformation two intrinsic functions in tag key
I'm trying to add tags to a Cloudformation resource that contain an output exported by another stack:
Resources:
  Nodegroup:
    Type: AWS::EKS::Nodegroup
    Properties:
      Tags:
        firstKey: firstValue
        !Sub randomString-${Fn::ImportValue: ClusterName}: true

But I'm getting validation errors because the function's colon is being interpreted as the value separator: Nested mappings are not allowed in compact mappings
Quoting as suggested here does not help since the function is then seen as a string and not executed.
I tried this form as suggested in the documentation:
!Sub
  - 'randomString-${ClusterName}: true'
  - ClusterName: !ImportValue ClusterName

But apart from getting a string instead of a needed object, I wouldn't know how to add more than one tag.
Is there a way to achieve what I need?

You can do it like this:
Resources:
  Nodegroup:
    Type: AWS::EKS::Nodegroup
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: firstKey
          Value: firstValue
        - Key:
            Fn::Join:
              - ''
              - - 'randomString-'
                - Fn::ImportValue: ClusterName
          Value: 'true'
            

